# problem with assigning value to a 2d array javascript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

the problem I have is when I associate value in the 2d array on a certain row and column, that value will be stored on several rows on the same column

```
var Matrix = Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(0));
console.log(Matrix);
Matrix[1][2]=1;
console.log(Matrix);
```

```
and the output is : 

/// the 2d array 
[ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]
/// after 'Matrix[1][2]=1'
[ [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ]
```

Comment: You're assigning a reference to the same "inner" array to all the positions in the outer one.

Comment: `const matrix = Array.from(Array(3), () => Array(3).fill(0));`

Comment: @Andreas so what are you saying is that : all those arrays are just like mirrors , they are the same thing , right ? if is that then thanks .

Comment: @picantultunic Yes.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts your method work for me , thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The tree sub-arrays you are declared in the first line, are refered to the same array, like a pointer.

try something like this:

```
var Matrix = []
Matrix.push(Array(3).fill(0))
Matrix.push(Array(3).fill(0))
Matrix.push(Array(3).fill(0))
console.log(Matrix);
Matrix[1][2]=1;
console.log(Matrix);
```

Output

```
/// the 2d array 
[ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]
/// after 'Matrix[1][2]=1'
[ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Comment: it's working , thanks .